# CORS headers missing errors with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I am getting the following error in javascript with chrome.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://stream.example.com/' from origin 'http://test.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

`http://stream.example.com/` has the following headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

Both `http://stream.example.com/` and `http://test.example.com` are aliases to localhost since i am currently developing the app.

What is wrong here ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56467419/6514992

Comment: @FouèdMoussi if you check my post i already added those headers

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you using barryvdh laravel-cors [package](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)